# How to write function for multiple analog pins? (arduino)

Tags: c++, function, arduino

So I'm writing this little function for some pot pins. The pot sends a value only when its being turned, at rest, it sends nothing. Which is how I want it to function.

It works fine with one pin.

I've gotten it to a point where it half works with multiple pins. So if I call it twice in the loop with two pins, I get back the right values on both those pins. But I loose the functionality of the if statement. Basically I can't figure out the last half of this. Arrays have been suggested I'm just unsure of how to proceed.

Suggestions? Thank you.

```
    byte pots[2] = {A0, A2};


int lastPotVal = 0;


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

}


void loop(){

  // get the pin out of the array
  rePot(pots[0]); 
  rePot(pots[1]); 
  delay(10);

}

void rePot(const int potPin){


  // there is probably an issue around here somewhere...


  int potThresh = 2;
  int potFinal = 0; 
  int potVal = 0; 

  // set and map potVal

  potVal = (analogRead(potPin));         
  potVal = map(potVal, 0, 664, 0, 200);  

    if(abs(potVal - lastPotVal) >= potThresh){

      potFinal = (potVal/2);       
      Serial.println(potFinal);

      lastPotVal = potVal; 



     }   // end of if statement

} // end of rePot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a `struct` to mange a pot and the data associated with it (the pin it's on, the last reading, threshold, etc). Then, the `rePot()` function is changed to take one of those structs as input, instead of just the pin number.

```
struct Pot {
    byte pin;
    int threshold;
    int lastReading;
    int currentReading;
};

// defining an array of 2 Pots, one with pin A0 and threshold 2, the
// other with pin A2 and threshold 3. Everything else is automatically
// initialized to 0 (i.e. lastReading, currentReading). The order that
// the fields are entered determines which variable they initialize, so
// {A1, 4, 5} would be pin = A1, threshold = 4 and lastReading = 5
struct Pot pots[] = { {A0, 2}, {A2, 3} };

void rePot(struct Pot * pot) {
    int reading = map(analogRead(pot->pin), 0, 664, 0, 200);

    if(abs(reading - pot->lastReading) >= pot->threshold) {
        pot->currentReading = (reading/2);
        Serial.println(pot->currentReading);
        pot->lastReading = reading;
    }
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    rePot(&pots[0]);
    rePot(&pots[1]);
    delay(10);
}
```

A slightly different take on this is to change `rePot()` into a function that takes the whole array as input, and then just updates the whole thing. Like this:

```
void readAllThePots(struct Pot * pot, int potCount) {
    for(int i = 0; i < potCount; i++) {
        int reading = map(analogRead(pot[i].pin), 0, 664, 0, 200);

        if(abs(reading - pot[i].lastReading) >= pot[i].threshold) {
            pot[i].currentReading = (reading/2);
            Serial.println(pot[i].currentReading);
            pot[i].lastReading = reading;
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    readAllThePots(pots, 2);
    delay(10);
}
```

Comment: Just one question for my own learning purposes: 

rePot(struct Pot * pot)  ...is this just re-naming "Pot" to "pot"? I'm used to * being multiply, so wondering what this means in this statement, and why its done.

Comment: In this case, * specifies a pointer. So, the function takes a pointer to a Pot struct, and that pointer is named "pot". The use of "struct" in the function definition is a bit of a weird corner of C, and one way it differs from C++. You can basically ignore "struct", and just read it as "rePot(Pot * pot)", which translates to "a function called rePot, which takes a pointer to a Pot called pot. It might've been clearer to call it something like rePot(Pot * theInputPot)

Comment: Additional question: I have a little blinkLED function elsewhere in the program, I use it for buttons mostly. it just does an onlength / offlength where the offlength is a delay. I was trying to use it w/ this. But the delay if its above 50 will cause the pot to have messed up readings. Why does that tend to happen? I'm guessing its because the delay is slowing down the rate of the pot reading as it loops through?

Comment: Hard to say.. possibly the LED is drawing enough power to make the analogRead mess up? Instead of using a delay, you could have a variable called offTime. When a button is triggered, you set offTime to be now + 50 milliseconds. Every loop() you check whether millis() is greater or less then offTime, and turn the led on or off accordingly. This lets you keep grabbing pot readings while blinking the LEDs. Almost like threading :)

Comment: Yep, power related. Adjusted. :)

Hopefully last question: If I want to replace a value in that pots array from say the loop, or setup. Normally I would do something like: **array[0][1] = x;** For this my brain wants to write something like: **struct Pot pots[0][1] = 10;** but I get an _"array must be initialized with brace enclosed initializer"_  I am unsure how to solve that.

Also thanks for taking the time to make suggestions / feedback.

Comment: You can set a Pot's values by name, instead of by index. So, to set the currentReading of the pot at index 3, you could do pots[3].currentReading = 42